# iphone - numberOfRowsInSection being called before viewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

This might be normal, but I'm new to objective-c.
I have an app with two view controllers, both are table views.
When a row is clicked, I load the second view to the top of the stack and pass a parameter through one of it's properties.
On the first view (loaded by default by the navigation controller) the viewDidAppear function is called first, it opens an XML file from a URL, builds an object for each node and pushes all the objects in to an array. After this is done, numberOfRowsInSection is called and it returns the count for the array and all is well.
On the other view, after it is loaded first the numberOfRowsInSection is called and then viewDidAppear. I'm really new to the iphone and I have no idea why this is even happening.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for taking the time to reply!
I found the issue.
Being new to xcode/iphone/mvc, I forgot to connect the view to the IBOutlet object.
A few hours of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: I'm afraid to say i've been a victim of this n00b mistake a few times.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal. `viewDidAppear` is called after the entire view is has finished loading and became visible.
This includes the `UITableView`. The Table View in turn requires the `numberOfRowsInSection` function to initialize.

You have three options to execute code before the `UITableView` loads:

1) Place your code in `-viewWillAppear` - this can occasionally be shaky

2) Subclass the UIViewController (chances are you are already doing this) and create a custom `-init` function to handle your setup

3) Put your initialization code inside of `-numberofRowsInSection`. This is always the first method of the `UITableViewDataSource` to be called. It is hackish but works very well in practice.

Comment: In most cases, data loading code does not go to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, 'cause it is usually unnecessary to reload the view after appearance/disappearance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider moving your code to  `-viewWillAppear` or `-viewDidLoad` .

Comment: Well it works for one view, why does it not work for the other?

Comment: After the data loading, just `[tableView reloadData]` to update the view.

Comment: @Elad: UITableView presumably loads cells lazily (probably in -layoutSubviews). On an non-animated transition, -viewWillAppear: and -viewDidAppear: are both called immediately; on an animated transition, the table view has to lay out before it can start animating onto the screen.